# 24LC1025 Arduino - Data Writing Problem

Tags: programming, eeprom

I have a very big problem by writing a list of strings to an eeprom (24LC1025) Your help with my problem highly appericiated.

I have a data matrix, PageData[111][96] and I want to write all them at once, line by line to the eeprom. I am using arduino for coding.

the code is :

```
{

#include <Wire.h>

#define EEPROM_ADDR 0xA0;

void setup()
{

  Wire.begin();         

  Serial.begin(9600);
int PageData[111][96]={ my data is here ... }

 for (t=0; t<111; t++){                                   
  for (unsigned long i=0; i<96; i++){     
    m=i*2;
    value[m] = highByte(PageData[t][i]);
    value[m+1] = lowByte(PageData[t][i]);   }

  at=((t*192));

 for (unsigned long i=0; i< 192; i++) {            
    i2c_eeprom_write_byte(EEPROM_ADDR,(at+i),value[i]);   
    delay(5);                             }
      }

void i2c_eeprom_write_byte( int deviceaddress, unsigned long eeaddress, byte data )
{
if( eeaddress > 65535 )
    deviceaddress = deviceaddress | B00001000;    

    deviceaddress = deviceaddress >> 1;  

  byte rdata = data;
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceaddress);
  Wire.write((int)(eeaddress >> 8));    // Address High Byte
  Wire.write((int)(eeaddress & 0xFF));  // Address Low Byte
  Wire.write(rdata);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

My problem in this code: when I want to read the eeprom for the checking the strings, I realize, it does not write the eeprom the whole 111 line. It just writes randomly sometimes half of this sometimes less than this amount.

I tried several ways to solve the problem. but now I am desperate , please check this and tell me where i miss a point. Please let me know, if any information you need for the answer.

Comment: 111 x 96 x 2 Byte = 21312 Byte. How is this supposed to fit into your maybe 4096 Bytes SRAM? You're probably getting a stack overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: @brhans: I am not talking about the Flash, I am refering to the SRAM of the Arduino controller. "Stack overflow" has nothing to do with external storage.

Comment: @Rev1.0 - doh - I should read more carefully - didn't even consider that the OP might be messing up the basics ...

Comment: arduino due has 96kbyte SRAM not 4096 bytes.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue

Comment: @AhmedTarhan: Granted, but you left us guessing what kind of Arduino you have. And since most have 8-bit controllers with very little ram, limited SRAM was a potential issue.

Comment: @AhmedTarhan. You have to clarify what hardware/software are you using. What run in Arduino Uno doesn't run in NodeMCU. As a rule, you have to says what libraries and IDE are you using,

Answer (score 1):

Writing a single byte is really bad. You are causing a page write with each bye, and each page has a limited lifetime (100,000 - 1,000,000 cycles) so use block instead.

> When writing any amount of data, including a single byte using this
>   function,   the EEPROM will refresh the entire page (128 bytes) of
>   data.   EEPROMs have a limited write endurance (often 1 million cycles
>   per page).   Therefore, if you write one byte at a time, instead of
>   writing a full block   at once, you are *wasting the chip's lifetime*
>   (doing so is also MUCH slower).   ONLY use this if you really only
>   need to write ONE byte, and avoid it   when you can.   Using a block
>   write (below), you can write 128 bytes and only use a single   page
>   write (or *at most* two, if the write is not aligned to a page
>   boundary).

This library should do the trick for you:
https://github.com/exscape/electronics/tree/master/Arduino/Libraries/EEPROM/EEPROM_24XX1025

Comment: Duh! Please, expand your answer. Other than avoid unnecesary writings, I haven't found much about EEPROMs. Is your info valid for all kinds of EEPROM?

Comment: Im sorry buddy, I don't get what you mean? Expand my answer of not writing one byte at a time? I referenced a well written out description on why, and a library that will take care of writing with pages. If you need more information, you can click on the link and *read* about which modules are supported. Do you need help for a specific module, or a specific scenario? The original post is about a 24LC1025 module, which is supported for the first block (64KB) by the referenced library.